# Value of toggle switch in html and flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I am building a webapp which has a form element using a toggle switch to send an options value in Flask/Python.

When I keep the toggle switch on, I am getting the value as expected('check) but when I keep the toggle button off and hit the submit button, I get a bad request error saying :

Bad Request
The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Below is the code for the form :

```
<form  action=" {{url_for('process_query')}}" 
method="post">

<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" name="check" value="check"> 
<span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<input class="input is-rounded" type="text" name="query" value="">

<button class="button is-rounded is-primary">Start!</button>
```

Below is the code for the *process_query* function:

```
@app.route('/process_query', methods = ['GET', 
'POST'])
def process_query():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print ("value of checkbox is " + 
               request.form['check'])
more code
```

Can someone please tell me why I get this error and what changes are needed in this code?

Comment: I think this is caused by the fact that request.form['check'] doesn't exist if you submit without checking. Try print (request.form['check']) and submit an empty checkbox. Also not sure on your print command, I would write this as follows: print ("value of checkbox is ", request.form['check']). Both syntax are probably valid ways of printing..

Comment: print (request.form['check']) with an empty checkbox gives the same error. Does this mean we can't have an empty checkbox submitted to flask?!

Comment: Indeed, if no checkbox is filled, the post request will not contain any checkbox nor values of checkboxes. For a solution you could wrap it in an if statement of try-except.